# Deducción parcial de parámetros en clase plantilla (característica C++17)

Tags: c++, template, c++1z

Mi idea de la característica de C++17 [*Deducción de parámetros de plantilla para clases plantilla*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html) era que se pretendía homogeneizar el comportamiento de las funciones plantilla y las clases plantilla en los casos de deducción de parámetros. Pero creo que hay algo que no he entendido.

Si tenemos este objeto plantilla:

```
template <std::size_t S, typename T>
struct test
{
    static constexpr auto size = S;
    using type_t = T;

    test(type_t (&input)[size]) : data(input) {}
    type_t (&data)[size]{};
};
```

Habitualmente uso una función de ayuda para facilitar la creación de objetos `test`:

```
template <std::size_t S, typename T>
test<S, T> helper(T (&input)[S]) { return input; }
```

Que puede ser usada de la siguiente manera:

```
int main()
{
    int buffer[5];

    auto a = helper<5, int>(buffer); // Sin deduccion.
    auto b = helper<5>(buffer);      // Tipo deducido.
    auto c = helper(buffer);         // Tipo y tamanyo deducidos.

    std::cout << a.size << b.size << c.size;

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra `555` como era de esperar. He probado lo mismo en Wandbox usando los compiladores más nuevos<sup>1</sup>:

```
int main()
{
    int buffer[5];

    test<5, int> a(buffer); // Sin deduccion: Funciona.
    test<5> b(buffer);      // Tipo deducido: FALLO.
    test c(buffer);         // Tipo y tamanyo deducidos: Funciona.

    std::cout << a.size << b.size << c.size;

    return 0;
}
```

Parece que la deducción de parámetros para clases plantilla sólo funciona cuando se deducen todos los parámetros, estaba esperando que ambos comportamientos (la deducción por función y por clase) fueran iguales, ¿hay algo que no haya entendido?

---

<sup>1</sup>Los últimos compiladores disponibles en Wandbox son *gcc HEAD 7.0.1 201701* y *clang HEAD 5.0.0 (trunk)*.

Comment: Hace mucho que no trabajo que c++ ademas no cuento con la experiencia c++17 para responder a tu pregunta, pero quizas este link te ayude a comprender http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html, en el apartado h2 The Solution si no quieres o no puedes leer todo quizas te ayude a saber si es lo que buscas.

Comment: ¿No es el mismo documento que enlazo en mi pregunta? ;)

Comment: Yo diría que sí... el enlace es el mismo

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Creo que deberías hacer una colecta de las respuestas que te han hecho en la versión inglesa y publicar una respuesta... No sería correcto que lo hiciese yo después de haber puesto la recompensa

Comment: @eferion tampoco me parece correcto responder a mi propia pregunta y llevarme una recompensa por ello.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Al menos tu te has molestado en publicarla en otros sitios donde sí has podido obtener respuestas

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Además no es por la recompensa, que la reputación es lo de menos, considero que la pregunta es importante que tenga respuesta...

Comment: PaperBirdMaster disculpa fallo mio, si es cierto que es el mismo, simplemente al leer la pregunta me parecio interesante y me centre durante un momento en el codigo que pusistes que me olvide de mirar el link, antes de ponerme a buscar por google. @eferion Yo diría que sí... pues si tienes toda la razon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Las respuestas que se muestran a continuación están extraídas de [la misma pregunta en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833630/c17-class-template-partial-deduction) (Por favor, dad el crédito merecido a los autores originales).

Ambas respuestas vienen a decir que en el propio documento técnico no está claro que la deducción parcial de parámetros de plantilla en clases plantilla esté permitida y que **se desestimó la deducción parcial** por resultar confuso. Como podemos ver en los ejemplos de la pregunta la deducción total funciona.

---

#### [Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41834419/499359)

Parece haber una contradicción en el propio documento técnico de [*Deducción de parámetros de plantilla para clases plantilla*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html); se indica que la especificación parcial de parámetros debería estar permitida (la traducción es mía, el resaltado de la respuesta original):

> Proponemos que el nombre de plantilla pueda referirse a la clase plantilla como especificador-simple-de-tipo o **con parámetros explícitamente proporcionados de manera parcial** en dos contextos:

Pero *en el texto del estándar* sobre la misma propuesta no se proporciona una manera de tratar "parámetros explícitamente proporcionados de manera parcial".

---

#### [metalfox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854832/499359)

Extraído del [informe del viaje](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2016/07/06/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-oulu-june-2016/)<sup>1</sup> de Botond Ballo:

> Esta característica originalmente contenía dedución parcial, en que explicitamente se especificaban algunos de los parámetros de la plantilla, y se dejaba el resto para ser deducidos, pero se desestimó por la preocupación de que pudiera ser confuso en algunos casos:
>
> ```
> // Deberia deducir tuple<int, string, float>,
> // pero tuple<int> es un tipo correctamente formado por si mismo!
> tuple<int> t(42, "waldo", 2.0f);
> ```

---

<sup>1</sup>Informe del viaje se refiere a que el autor del blog (Botond Ballo) partició en el encuentro del comité de estándares que tuvo lugar en [Oulu](https://www.google.es/maps/place/Oulu) en Junio de 2016. El autor del blog "*There's Waldo!*" informa de las convesaciones que pudo presenciar allí.